# Why Empty message in std_msg?

Tags: ros, std-msgs, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As in the title, I don't understand why is there an `Empty` type in `std_msgs`? What is it used for?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/324043/why-empty-message-in-std_msg?/) by [Sparkle Eyes](https://answers.ros.org/users/38320/sparkle-eyes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 99 on 2019-05-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It can be useful in situations where you don't particularly care about content of a message, but just that one has been received. Example: maybe a bump sensor would use an empty message because you just care that you hit something, there may be no other information available worth giving a client.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2019-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sparkle Eyes](https://answers.ros.org/users/38320/sparkle-eyes/) on 2019-05-27**:
Thanks Steve for the answer and the example!